# Where do I start and what must I learn to make a website like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know the basics of HTML and CSS. What else do I have to know to make a website like this: http://www.wearetopsecret.com/
The first thing that pops up in my mind is Javascript and jQuery, but is that alone enough? And would it normally require years of experience to be able to code this from scratch?

Comment: A lot of experience and creativity. You can start learning JS in sites like [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/?gclid=CPzgzYKF-scCFYM-aQodu_AOng) and [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really not the place for this type of question. SO is for specific answers to technical questions. That being said, the page to which you refer uses jQuery and AngularJS. along with many jquery plugins. They also have a staff of Developers and Designers. And yes they have years of experience.

You can use Chrome's Developer tools to view the source of the page and the files that are being used to create it. This can often show you how things are done.

If you want to be able to build sites like this, learn more than just the basics of HTML and CSS. Learn about the javascript libraries that are available and what can be done with them (https://www.javascripting.com/).

Then get a job with a web design team that is better than you are. Learn from your co-workers and put in the years. It will be worth it both financially and professionally.

Answer (score 0):

A very general question.
You need to be more specific, but look HTML5, CSS3, javascript, jquery and another javascript frameworks.